# Conda uninstall package without name

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, conda

I have installed a python package I have written myself inside a `conda` virtual environment (using a call to `distutils.setup` in a `setup.py` script, I assume the scripts exact layout is not relevant here but feel free to correct me) but forgot to include the `name` parameter of the `setup` function call so that when I run `conda list` the package shows up as:

```
Name     Version  Build
UNKNOWN  0.0.0    <pip>
```

How can I uninstill this package again? `conda uninstall UNKNOWN` does not work. The package is not exactly harmful but this is not the first time this has happened to me and I find it somewhat annoying.

Comment: delete the package fromm site-packages then do conda update conda . i don't know if this a right way or not